# jinja: Escape variable + concatenate

Tags: python, html, escaping, jinja2

Hy

I know i can escape a variable by piping the variable through the |e filter.
But if i concatenate the variable with another string, everything gets escaped:

```
{% set escaped =  "<div></div>"|e %}
{{ '<div>'+escaped+'</div>' }}
```

Results in:

```
<div><div></div></div>
```

How can i only escape the variable, so the rest of the string will be interpeted as HTML?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the Solution:

```
{% set escaped =  "<div></div>"|e %}
{{ '<div>'|safe + escaped + '</div>'|safe  }}
```